# ¿Cómo hacer para que un objeto de una clase sea accesible desde todo los métodos pero individual para cada usuario?

Tags: c#, asp.net

¿Cómo hacer para que un objeto de una clase sea accesible desde todo los métodos pero individual para cada usuario?

Tengo una app que hace una encuesta y va guardando las respuestas del usuario (que se identifica en la intranet por el usuario de Windows) en un objeto perteneciente a una clase custom. Necesito que a ese objeto se pueda acceder desde todos los métodos, pero no que se comparta entre los distintos usuarios que usen la app a la verdad.

Probé este código:

```
    public class SurveyETA
    {

        public static string Question1 { get; set; }
        public static string Question2 { get; set; }
        public static string Question3 { get; set; }

        public static string Question4 { get; set; }

        public static string Question5 { get; set; }

        public static string Question6 { get; set; }
    }


    public static SurveyETA RespondentETA = new SurveyETA();
```

Pero por lo que pude comprobar ese objeto "RespondentETA" comparte su contenido por cada usuario y eso hace que las respuestas en memoria son sobreescritas por el segundo usuario que opera el sistema.

Comment: Por qué las propiedades de esa clase son `static`? Alguna razón en particular? Intenta cambiarlas por *public* y nos cuentas qué tal te va.

Comment: Probé con public sin static y pasa lo mismo. Sin public en los métodos del código por más que puedo acceder al objeto, da error al intentar acceder a la propiedad que no es public.

Comment: Si ya intentaste sólo dejándolas public, **incluyendo** la línea `public SurveyETA RespondentETA = new SurveyETA()`, entonces, habría que ver el resto del proyecto/solución. Sólo viendo esta clase no creo que solucionemos un problema que parece ser más grande